# How to copy the value in a range of cells to another cell if only one cell in the range has a value?

Tags: excel, formula

I have 40 columns and several hundred rows in an Excel spreadsheet.

```
Range C6:AQ6, C7:AQ7, C8:AQ8, and so on

CASE 1: Only one cell in the range D6:AQ6 usually contains a value. 
CASE 2: In some rare cases, more than one cell OR no cells contain a value in this range.
```

Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
If CASE 1: Populate the cell C6 with the value in the only cell in the range D6:AQ6.
If CASE 2: Leave C6 blank
```

How do I do this using Excel formulae?

Comment: Values are text, or numeric? You can use COUNTA() to count non-blank values (unless the cells have formulas).

Comment: Values are text. I am able to count, but how do I copy the only value in the range? Use 40 nested IFs?

Comment: You could concatenate all the values....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula into Cell C6:

```
=IF(COUNTA(D6:AQ6)=1,INDEX(D6:AQ6,Match("*",D6:AQ6,0)),"")
```

How it works:

- Count's how many Cells in the range "D6:AQ6" are not blank.

  - If there is only 1 cell with data (Case1)

    - Then use index to return the value

      - Index works by returning the value form the cell X to the right where X is the first column Match finds that has anything inside of it
  - If there is not 1 (more than 1 or 0, Case2)

    - then set the cell to blank

Comment: Oops. The return key posted my comment before I completed it.

Comment: Gaaah!! OK, so here is my comment:

Thanks. This worked with two small modifications:

1. The seemingly blank cells in 'D6:AQ6' are apparently not blank (maybe because I copied the values from elsewhere?). So I used '=IF(COUNTIF(D6:AQ6,"?*")=1,' instead of COUNTA and that fixed the problem.

2. Because of the '0' in 'Match("*",D6:AQ6,0)' this formula shows the very first cell in the range, because the first cell - even if it does not contain a value, it is not really blank. So I used '"?*"' instead of '"*"'.

Comment: I see I didnt anticipate there being the blank spaces. I'm glad you were able to figure it out though. :]